# Automating mkdir, chmod and scp across all the servers

Tags: linux, shell, scp, chmod

This seems to be a simple issue but, I'm not able to figure it out. I am trying to run a couple of small scripts on a server and i'm having issues with that. i have an allhosts file that has the list of servers which is in the same location as that of the .sh file.

script to create a directory structure across all the 20 servers with 777 permissions

```
#!bin/bash
for q in `cat allhosts`
do
ssh $q "mkdir -p /opt/acd/hgf/tom/hanks/"
chmod -R 777 $q "/opt/acd/hgf/tom/hanks/" >/dev/null 2>&1
done
```

in the above script, it is only creating the directory paths and not changing the permissions for that path. I tried running that chmod command in a separate script, but no use..

script to scp the contents of hanks to the hanks folder created in the new server.

```
#!bin/bash
for q in `cat allhosts`
do
scp /opt/acd/hgf/tom/hanks/* $q:/opt/acd/hgf/tom/hanks/ >/dev/null 2>&1
done
```

in this script too, when i run it, its not copying anything to any of the servers.

i know this is a very small issue, but please check and let me know where I am going wrong. thanks in advance..

Comment: You're running chmod on your local machine. chmod doesn't know how to log in to a remote machine and do stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first script is failing because it is running the `chmod` on the local machine.  You should run it on the remote machine via `ssh` - you could combine this with the other `ssh` invocation as follows:

```
ssh $q "mkdir -p /opt/acd/hgf/tom/hanks/ ; chmod -R 777 /opt/acd/hgf/tom/hanks/"
```

I'd guess the second script is failing because the first script isn't setting permissions; it looks okay.

Comment: thanks for that tip, yes the first script ran fine.. but still nothing is being copied while using the second script.. am i missing something?

Comment: Try `scp /opt/acd/hgf/tom/hanks/* ${q}:/opt/acd/hgf/tom/hanks/`.  (Why are you redirecting the output to `/dev/null`?  If you at least redirected it to a log file you'd be able to see error messages - this might give you some idea what is going on and how to fix it.)